# Precision/std of points based on hitting an area target

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

I've have the following situation.

I am scanning a circular area target with a known radius and location.  I receive back points that hit that target along with a location for the point.  However, because my scan is not perfectly precise the location of the points I get back do not necessarily fall within that target.  All I know is that they actual do come from hitting the target.  I'd like to know how to calculate the precision of a single point based on my returned points.  I can assume the the precision is the same in both x,y directions.

[image: target image]

My assumption is that I should do the following: 
   a) Calculate the mean of the returned points 
   b) Calculate a variance based of the distance of each point from the mean 
   c) Subtract the variance of my actual points with the variance of points if they hit with equal probability on every point on the target.
   d) The resulting variance will represent the variance of a single point.

Is this correct, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It is not clear what your setup is. Is there noise involved in the readings or a systematic error?

Comment: There is noise in the system.  Any systematic error should have been calibration out.  To clarify further, these are Lidar returns from a target, but the angles that I get back (which determines the position) are based on timing information which has some unquantified (hopefully gaussian) noise.  The position returned is thus noisy.

Comment: How do you define precision? How is it related to the variance?

Comment: I am defining precision as the standard deviation of the euclidean distance of a reported point from its actual position. (I can assume average error is zero).  So if I could use a point target (rather than area) it would simply be the square root of the variance of reported points from their mean.